# Python 3 bs4 crawling links issue and list of dictionnaries problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

It's been a while i didn't crawl web and i get blocked on a website...

If i inspect the page with chrome i will see all links in source but when using bs4 with python 3 the soup will not contain any links !

As i'm a newbie in crawling i would like someone to explain to me please :)

Is it due to the agent ? is it definitely impossible to crawl this page ?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url="https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/grilles/resultats"
request_headers={'User-Agent': "(Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6" }


r = requests.get(url,headers=request_headers)
req_txt=r.text
if r.status_code==200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_txt, u'html5lib')
    print(soup.prettify())
    links_pak=[url + u'/' + node.get(u'href') for node in soup.find_all(u'a')] #if node.get(u'href').endswith(ext)]
    print("links : ",links_pak)
else:
    print(r.status_code)
```

Edit : After some researchs i found it's due to JS front code, so i looked at the network behaviour and found some API calls that i should be able to use for what i need.

So here comes my list of dictionnaries problem, so i have the code below :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url="https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/api/loto-foot/list"

r = requests.get(url)
req_txt=r.text
if r.status_code==200:
    print(r.json())
    list_all=r.json()

else:
    print(r.status_code)
```

I looked many documention, and i understand how to filter dicts on key value or see if there is a value in a list of dicts but what i would like is to check in my list of dicts (e.g list_all) if there is a key:value tuple in a dict, if so retrieve the data of this dict only !

In my example if you run the code snipet you will see in the dicts there is a 'sportId' key , i want to get dicts only where 'sportId:100' is true...I'm a bit confused in dict comprehension....

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Possible you should look at full-featured web browser with automatisation ([selenium-python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)?), because many websites get data through JavaScript requests (XMLHttpRequest), which may be hard to obtain by  `requests`/`curl`/`wget`. In your case look at url https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/api/loto-foot/results?numberItem=20&startItem=0

Comment: yeah i found out this api adress i don't know if i will use it or only matchs to come :) Still i don't know how to select the dictionnaries that are useful for me :((( I edited my post to explain with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after many tries with list comprehension i found out how to do...

So here's the code snippet working :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url="https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/api/loto-foot/list"

r = requests.get(url)
req_txt=r.text
if r.status_code==200:
    list_all=r.json()
    list_foot=[d for d in list_all if d['sportId']==100] #Filters foot results only
    print(list_foot)

else:
    print(r.status_code)
```